# Would I need a web framework if the app is running locally and not in the net?

Tags: c#, design, javascript, python

I need to make an Employee Payroll application and the client specifically stated that the application will run on their computer locally and will not be hosted anywhere in the internet.

I can  code in **Javascript**, **C#** and in **Python**. I was thinking of using **Electron** for my front-end so that I don't have to worry about cross-platform but I'm not entirely sure if I need a web framework ( that's only used locally ) to access the database.

The reason I am thinking of a web framework is because I need an export/import to excel support and both C# and Python have great support for that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web frameworks are for server-end applications.
FYI a desktop app can do the job.
Third-party libraries which support Excel exporting/importing would work well without a web framework.